# Validation error not displaying with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, devexpress

I have been struggle with this now for two days and I do not know where the problem is.

When I leave the textbox the Ajax call is correct and the result are returned as a true or false and the success: function is executing.

The problem is that the image and error text is not displaying next to the textbox. If I type in more than 50 characters in the textbox the "Must be under 50 characters" message is showing but it I type in a user name that already exist the message is not showing.

What am I missing? Any suggestions?

**I use a DevExpress Text Box**

```
Html.DevExpress().Label(
        edtSettings =>
        {
            edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
            edtSettings.Text = "User Name:";
            edtSettings.AssociatedControlName = "UserName";
        }
    )
    .Render();
    Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
        edtSettings =>
        {
            edtSettings.Name = "UserName";
            edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "editor";
            edtSettings.ShowModelErrors = true;
            edtSettings.Width = 100;
            edtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.Assign(IserValidationHelper.UserNameValidationSettings);
            edtSettings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.Validation = "OnNameValidation";
            edtSettings.ControlStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
        }
        )
        .Bind(DataBinder.Eval(IserUser, "UserName"))
        .Render();
```

**I have the following JavaScript.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function OnNameValidation(s, e) {

    if (e.value == null)
        e.isValid = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Admin/CheckUsername',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { userName: e.value },
        error: function () { alert("error"); },
        success: function (Data) {
            if (Data.result == true) {
                e.isValid = false;
                e.errorText = "User Exits";
            };
        }
    });

    var name = e.value;
    if (name == "")
        e.isValid = false;

    if (name.length > 50) {
        e.isValid = false;
        e.errorText = "Must be under 50 characters";
    }

}
```

**I have the following method in my controller.**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckUsername(string userName)
    {
        bool status = WebSecurity.UserExists(userName);
        return Json(new { result = status });
    }
```

[image: JSON Result]

[image: JSON Result 2]

Comment: "The problem is that the image and error text is not displaying next to the textbox" - I don't see anything in the JavaScript that is even trying to display anything?

Comment: Ah, ok, does your returned JSON data contain a `result` property with a boolean `true` value? if so, it should set the properties. If not it will enter the success function but do nothing.

Comment: @scunliffe The JSON result is true and the properties are set, checked it in debugging. What I also realize in the debugging is that the `OnNameValidation` function is executed in full and then only afterwords the success: function is executed.

Comment: can you post the full JSON response string?

Comment: @scunliffe See image added.

Comment: I notice that at the time that the JSON success: function set the properties the focus is already on the next textbox.

Comment: Just re-read your comment 4 above... did you expect/want the AJAX call to be synchronous? (currently it is asynchronous) thus the success (or error) will likely happen after the rest of the function has executed.

Comment: @scunliffe I feel like an idiot. I new there was something small that I overlooked. I add `async:false,` to my ajax and eureka it work. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my $.ajax call. I had to include the setting **async** (`async:false,`) as the default async is true. It is working now correctly.

```
function OnNameValidation(s, e) {

    if (e.value == null)
        e.isValid = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ISERAdmin/CheckUsername',
        dataType: 'json',
        async:false,
        data: { userName: e.value },
        error: function () { alert("error"); },
        success: function (Data) {
            if (Data.result == true) {
                e.isValid = false;
                e.errorText = "User Exits";
            };
        }
    });

    var name = e.value;
    if (name == "")
        e.isValid = false;

    if (name.length > 56) {
        e.isValid = false;
        e.errorText = "Must be under 56 characters";
    }

}
```